# Access JBoss pool statistics on runtime

Tags: java, jboss, java-ee-6

I use JBoss EAP 6.2 in my project. I have configured the pool size for stateless beans (slsb-strict-max-pool) as x. I can see in a thread dump that some threads wait for some pooled instances.

Now I would like to monitor the used pool size of each @Stateless bean at runtime. So is there any way to access this information via some MXBean? So I can display somewhere that a @Stateless bean has allocated y of x pooled instances?

Thanks, Rokko

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you have already analyzed thread dump, I suppose you should know about jboss-cli. It shows the runtime metrics of jBoss EJB components. 
For example:

```
/deployment=ProjectEAR.ear/subdeployment=ProjectWAR.war/subsystem=ejb3/stateless-session-bean=StatelessEJBName  :read-resource(include-runtime=true, recursive=true) 
{
"outcome" => "success",
"result" => {
    "component-class-name" => "StatelessEJBName",
    "declared-roles" => [],
    "execution-time" => 0L,
    "invocations" => 0L,
    "methods" => {},
    "peak-concurrent-invocations" => 0L,
    "pool-available-count" => 20,
    "pool-create-count" => 1,
    "pool-current-size" => 1,
    "pool-max-size" => 20,
    "pool-name" => "slsb-strict-max-pool",
    "pool-remove-count" => 0,
    "run-as-role" => undefined,
    "security-domain" => "other",
    "timers" => [],
    "wait-time" => 0L,
    "service" => undefined
} }
```

It is not quite clear, do you want to get just runtime EJB statistics, or get EJB statistics programmatically from your appilcation?